# Generated column from another table's column

Tags: sqlite, group-by, view, sum, generated-columns

`Transaction` table:

| ID | Name | Price | Amount Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bruce Wayne | 10.0 | 5.0 |
| 2 | Lois Lane | 33.33 | 22.22 |
| 3 | Clark Kent | 44.4 | 44.4 |
| 4 | Bruce Wayne | 15.0 | 20.0 |

`Person` table:

| ID | Name | Total Price | Total Paid | Payment Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bruce Wayne | 25.0 | 25.0 | 0.00 |
| 2 | Lois Lane | 33.33 | 22.22 | 11.11 |
| 3 | Clark Kent | 44.4 | 44.4 | 0.00 |

`Transaction` table is connected to application and `Person` table has `ID` and `Name`. `PaymentDue` column calculates `TotalPrice - TotalPaid`. Both `TotalPrice` and `TotalPaid` columns are empty and have default value of `0.00`.

I want to generate/update `TotalPrice` and `TotalPaid`  from `Transaction` table's `Price` and `Amount Paid` column where `Transaction.Name = Person.Name`.

I'm trying to create table with :

```
CREATE TABLE "Person" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "TotalPrice"    REAL AS (SUM("main.Transaction.Price") WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = "Name"),
    "TotalPaid" REAL DEFAULT 0.00,
    "PaymentDue"    REAL NOT NULL AS ("TotalPrice" - "TotalPaid"),
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

It's giving an error:

> Execution finished with errors. Result: near "WHERE": syntax error At
> line 1: CREATE TABLE "Person" (   "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
> "Name"  TEXT,   "TotalPrice"    REAL AS (SUM("main.Transaction.Price")
> WHERE

I also tried :

```
"TotalPrice"    REAL AS (SELECT SUM("main.Transaction.Price") WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = "Name"),
```

Error :

> Execution finished with errors. Result: near "SELECT": syntax error At
> line 1: CREATE TABLE "Person" (   "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
> "Name"  TEXT,   "TotalPrice"    REAL AS (SELECT

Also :

```sql
"TotalPrice"    REAL AS (SUM(t.Price) FROM Transaction t WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = "Name"),
```

Error:

> Near "FROM" syntax error

This app is to check customer/vendor payments and inventory management. I created `Person` table with :

```
CREATE TABLE "Person" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "TotalPrice"    REAL DEFAULT 0.00,
    "TotalPaid" REAL DEFAULT 0.00,
    "PaymentDue"    REAL NOT NULL AS ("TotalPrice" - "TotalPaid"),
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

And `Transaction` table :

```
CREATE TABLE "Transaction" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "Price" REAL  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    "AmountPaid"    REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

I can do update query but don't know how to use `SUM()`.

Comment: `SUM` likely doesn't work on TEXT fields, only on numeric data.
Also `WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = "Name"` should likely be `WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = 'Name'`.
At least a single quotation mark would be used in most other SQL dialects for string literals.

Comment: Ahh, it's my bad in Question, i typed "Name" Instead of "Price", i edited it, but it gives me same error. In my Actual Code I have 9 Columns In `Transaction` Table And 7 In `Person` Table so instead of copy pasting i just typed it here, that's why i got wrong table column in there, sorry my bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a generated column, but it is not possible because the expression refers to a column of another table (not to mention that it does aggregation on this column).

This constraint is documented in Generated [Columns/Capabilities](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html#capabilities):

> The expression of a generated column can refer to any of the other
> declared columns in the table, including other generated columns, as
> long as the expression does not directly or indirectly refer back to
> itself.

So, the expressions:

```
SUM("main.Transaction.Price") WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = "Name"
```

and

```
SELECT SUM("main.Transaction.Price") WHERE "main.Transaction.Name" = "Name"
```

are not allowed.

What you should do, is create a View instead of a table:

```
CREATE VIEW view_Person AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) ID,
       Name,
       SUM(Price) TotalPrice,
       SUM(AmountPaid) TotalPaid,
       SUM(Price) - SUM(AmountPaid) PaymentDue
FROM "Transaction"
GROUP BY Name;
```

and get the resultset that you need by selecting from the view:

```
SELECT * FROM view_Person;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=6826390b9992a8559fbdb55773800252).

Comment: Thank You!! Just a quick question, can i use this **View** in my wpf c# application using queries just like normal Tables? or is there anything else like i have to create another table or some other query syntax? if there's good article about views then i would love to read it, Thanks once again!

Comment: @The.N00B.One you can create queries by using the view just like you would use a table. You can read more about views here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html and https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-view/

Comment: Thanks @forpas, its working as expected after creating view, one more question, How can i `SUM()` specific rows (`WHERE ID = 1`), in my `Transaction` table i have column named `TypeID` which basically `1` for  `Sale` and `2` for `Purchase`, and a column named `Weight` what i want is `PurchasedWeight - SaleWeight` for each product. i'm trying to do it like `SUM(Weight) WHERE (TypeID = 1) PurchasedWeight, SUM(Weight) WHERE (TypeID=2) SaleWeight`, haven't tried on my main db yet but this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d8fd7ac12455e6b2706fb914e394b877) gives me an error.

Comment: @The.N00B.One Use the FILTER clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=affa3b7bb7079a1261e26b67d3275599

Answer (score 1):

The expression of a generated column may only reference constant literals and columns within the same row, and may only use scalar deterministic functions. The expression may not use subqueries, aggregate functions, window functions, or table-valued functions.

Read the docs https://sqlite.org/gencol.html

Comment: i read Official document on Generate Column 2-4 times but i couldn't understand it properly (not native English speaker)  and was not sure what's wrong, but now Thanks To You and @forpas i'm sure that i can't use `Generate Always AS` to do stuff from other tables, Thank You!